# Simple way to install a setuptools python module without root access?

Tags: python, setuptools

Say I a have python module with a proper setup.py which I would like to install to my own user.

However a simple installation will fail as such, since it attempts to install globally on my system

```
% python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
copying src/somemodule.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/somemodule.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/somemodule.py'
```

I have root access to the machine. This is not the point.

Is there a way to install with setuptools (say, as a user-specific site-packages). I am not looking for virtualenv nor `python setup.py build`, but something in line with what I would be able to with pip as in

```
% pip install --user somemodule.py
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `--prefix` option like:

```
python setup.py install --prefix ~/.local
```

**EDIT:**
This is similar to using `--user`, which uses the user specific site-package (defined to be ~/.local on *nix as per [PEP 370](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/)) automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I missed this by not looking into `install --help` (did only on `--help` and `--help-commands`).

Comment: I have to add that finding this out I found that `--user` is a better suited option, since uses the default site-package for the user automatically.

Comment: I totally forgot about that one. I'll just add it to the answer. Thank you.